# Seeding and pivot tables?

Tags: laravel-4

I'm trying to popular a pivot table with ids in a seed.

```
$id = DB::table('products')->insertGetId(array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Product A',
            'published' => 1
        )
    ));

    DB::table('product_user')->insert(array(
        array(
            'product_id' => $id,
            'user_id' => '9999999999'
        )
    ));
```

Is the above the best way to do it? By getting an id via insertGetId and then putting it in the pivot table Is there a better way?

Also the above way gives an error:

```
 [ErrorException]                                                             
 preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement i  
 s an array
```

I suspect $id is an array, how can i get InsertGetId to return an int?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can `print_r` it and seek for the `id` attribute, and then call `$id->attribute` on the second insert.

**But...**

"Me myself", I like to use Eloquent. The mainly reason is: **'Cause it too god damm FUN**. Really, Eloquent it's one of the most beautful things I've ever seen in the programming world. I use to thought that `.NET` was a master piece of software (I was young and naive, though) but once a came across Laravel/Eloquent, I became so ***AMAZED***!

That being said, in my humble opinion, use Eloquent is the best way of doing it!

I'm assuming that you have a table called `products` and another called `users`, and you have a `product_user` table to make the connection. Using Eloquent, you can simply do this:

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
$product = Product::find($product_id);

$product->user->attach($user);
```

...I reacomend this approach for several reasons, but the first one is: is way more **readable**.

Well, I hope I ain't been too prolixous on my answer, and that it hope you and others.

Comment: Thanks, how do you insert the data with this example and subsequently get it's id so you can use find with it?

Comment: You need to have the `user` and `product` already inserted. You can do so by declaring a new product/user model object. `$product = new Product;`, put the data into it save it by `$product->save()` e then retrive by `$product->id`. Same applies to `user`.

Comment: Thanks, but as originally asked, how would this work with seeds?

Comment: ... the same way! Seeds are just a way of automatically fill you database, but they are just as a commom script.

Comment: How do I access $product though? DB::table is used in a seed?

Comment: You can use `DB::table`. As I said, you just need to `print_r` the `$id` attribute and search for the ID attribute and access it. But, I suggest you to use Eloquent. When you use Eloquent, you don't have to use `DB::table`. Like I said, it's a higher level way of doing it. Take a look at Laravel's Eloquent documentation.

Comment: Thanks but how would i use eloquent in a seed class?

Comment: First of all, you need to have a model for each table you have on the database. Thats how eloquent does the magic.
Take a look at it: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent